# C MySQL API compiler warning problem with redefinition while including header files

Tags: mysql, c, eclipse, compiler-warnings

I am compiling a simple c program to test the including of the library files on eclipse cygwin environment `mysql-connector-c-6.0.2`
The program

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
int main(int argv,char* argc[])
{
        printf("my SQL libraries successfully included\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the compiler errors as

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\MinGW\Workspace\sql_test\Debug
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/MinGW/Workspace/sql_test/Debug
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
In file included from ../sql_test.c:8:
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1416:1: warning: "floatget" redefined
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1232:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1417:1: warning: "floatstore" redefined
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1231:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1418:1: warning: "doubleget" redefined
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1220:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1419:1: warning: "doublestore" redefined
D:\mysql-connector-c-6.0.2\include/my_global.h:1225:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
Finished building: ../sql_test.c
```

I have verified the my_global.h file and the deceleration of these seems to be valid.

1. How to turn of these redefinition errors?
2. Where in eclipse and How do i set this "CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" to turn off this warning".

Here you can see the header file [my_global.h](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=v2bhFv9q) of

Comment: The compiler points out the exact lines of the duplicates. Is that not correct?

Comment: :| sorry not overloaded.I have pasted the link to the header file. What i am assuming is there should not be a problem with the source files as its a header of mysql c connector given by oracle .

Comment: They **do** define the same macro, depending on some other macros (perhaps from the configuration?). I can't follow through 1000's of lines of  nested #ifdefs, so cannot say exactly what is wrong.

Comment: you probably did a grep/function search.you are right in saying they depend #ifdefs.How would you run this program? could you check it? http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/#downloads to include in project and compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the warning, define `CYGWIN=nodosfilewarning` in the OS environment (control panel -> system -> advanced -> environment variables).  If that doesn't work, try logging out to make sure nothing is using the old environment.

For the redefine errors, as Bo says, the compiler is telling you exactly where your mistakes are.  If you don't understand them, then you should at least post those lines as part of your question.

Comment: I had posted the link to the header file.Could you please let me know what kind of compiler-setting is needed?. Its a standard library of the sql c connection .

Comment: That depends on what the desired behavior you want.  You'll need to go through all the `#ifdef/#else/#endif` declarations in there to decide which sections you think should be included and then determine why the vendor designed it to include different versions of the same `#define`.

Comment: well i commented out the the redefined functions. And left a marker at that point to check if anything breaks in the future.